# Temporary users in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm struggling with temporary users in Zend Framework 2. I want a CMS with temporary users. I give them a startdate and enddate, but i want to check if they're active AND the current date is between the start and enddate.

The "out of date" is no value in the database, so i can't check on the database. Is it possible to check in the login from zfcUser if a user is active AND not out of date?

My overview with users is working good with a check, so i get a other pictogram when a user is out of date. Example:

```
public function customState()
{
    $state = $this->getState();
    $curDate = new \DateTime('midnight');

    //if (state = 1 and current date after startdate) AND (current date before enddate OR enddate is empty)
    if (($state == '1' && $this->startdate <= $curDate) && ($curDate <= $this->enddate || !isset($this->enddate))) {
        $this->setState('1');   
    }

    //if state = 1 and currentDate NOT between start- and enddate, set state on 2
    elseif ($state == '1' && ($this->startdate > $curDate || $curDate > $this->enddate)) {
        $this->setState('2');
    } 

    //if state = 2, set state on 3
    elseif ($state == '2') {
        $this->setState('3');
    }
}
```

So I create a "customState" with "active", "out of date", and "inactive". But in the database i only have a state (with active and inactive) and the start and enddate. Someone an idea how to fix this?